Deteriorated Patio Door Molding
I have French Patio doors in my basement. The molding that holds the weather stripping on the left door is wood, however, the doors are metal. The molding also has an upward sliding lock at the top of the door and a sliding lock down at the bottom of the door. While the seal is still in good shape, the molding has significant damage and holes at the bottom. I would like to replace this wooden molding and the weather stripping to better seal the basement. Bugs and worms, wasps and other sorts of pests have found their way into our basement. I went to Lowe’s first as they give a military discount but they weren’t much help. I was wondering if this molding is sold separately or if it is sold as part of the French door set? I don’t need new doors but would love to purchase the molding.

Can you add a photo please?
